# Determine site url from site page

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I created a list of different webpages from several sites:

```
foreach ($site in $Sites){
Get-PnPListItem -List “Site Pages” -Query…
}
```

The list now contains different webpages from several sites:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>ID, title, GUID</td></tr>
<tr><td>100, Test, 1e43ffeb-ab60-4900-9ee6-8c341226e9xx</td></tr>
<tr><td>250, Headline, 1e43ffeb-ab60-4900-xxxx-8c341226e9cc</td></tr>
</table>
```

etc.

How can I determine from this data set which site the page comes from using Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following script to get the site url of the corresponding page:

```
foreach ($site in $Sites){
    $pages = Get-PnPListItem -List “Site Pages” -Query…
    foreach ($page in $pages) {
        $siteUrl = $site.Url
        $pageId = $page.Id
        $pageTitle = $page.FieldValues["Title"]
        $pageGuid = $page.FieldValues["GUID"]
        Write-Host "$siteUrl,$pageId,$pageTitle,$pageGuid"
    }
}
```